# Fatal error LNK1104: cannot open .lib (glloaD)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, glut, freeglut

I'm trying to read an online book called modern 3d graphics programming, but the way they give the reader source code is very strange. I've read this page countless times and tried to setup the folder just how he writes, but everytime i try i get the error posted in the title. The link is :

http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Building%20the%20Tutorials.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had forgotten to build my openGL sdk library before running my tutorial programs.